# How to extract only cells which contain a letter AND a number in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, postal-code

I have a series of addresses from which I need to extract postal codes.The data is very sloppily formatted (not separated, some with spacings some without etc..) meaning the only way I can think to extract the postcodes is to create a column to which is added only the values which contain *Text* and a *Number* as these are the only cells to contain the postal code.

[image]

The data is too messy to isolate exactly where the postcode lies but I would like something to return a result like above.

How could I return only cell O2 & P2 from the range K2:R2?

*Address here is made up

Comment: Is it always 2 cells that have the postal code?  Are you able to use the latest Excel in Office 365?  If no to both then VBA is the way to go.

Comment: No, some came joined together some not. I don't know which logic to go for though. Is it a case of return cell which includes 1 OR 2 OR 3..AND A OR B OR C..etc? I'm way out of my depth here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I believe that @DarrenBartrup-Cook has a better answer.  This quick dirty little UDF will do it bassed on the mix of numbers and text like asked.

```
Function pcode(rng As Range)
Dim rngt As Range
Dim chr As String
Dim i As Integer

For Each rngt In rng
    If Not IsNumeric(rngt) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(rngt)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(rngt, i, 1)) Then
                pcode = Trim(pcode & " " & rngt.Value)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next rngt
End Function
```

Put this in a module attached to the workbook, **NOT** the worksheet code or ThisWorkbook code.

You would call it from the sheet with this formula:

```
=pcode(I5:P5)
```

[image]

Comment: Genius! It works for about 95% of my records but I have a few errors, this is down to the piss-poor data I have, not your answer to my question though!

Answer (score 1):

For a VBA result you could use the code below.
In cell T2 enter `=GetPostCode(K2:R2)`,
or in VBA you can use `Debug.Print GetPostCode(Sheet1.Range("K2:N2"))`

I can't remember where I got the pattern from, but can probably be improved.

```
Public Function GetPostCode(AddressRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sAddressString As String

    For Each rCell In AddressRange
        sAddressString = sAddressString & " " & rCell.Value
    Next rCell
    sAddressString = Trim(sAddressString)

    GetPostCode = ValidatePostCode(sAddressString)

End Function

Public Function ValidatePostCode(strData As String) As Variant

    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object

    Dim UKPostCode As String

    'Pattern could probably be improved.
    UKPostCode = "(?:(?:A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]?|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[CHNX]?|F[KY]|G[LUY]?|" _
                & "H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]?|M[EKL]?|N[EGNPRW]?|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKLMNOPRSTWY]?|" _
                & "T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ACDFNRSV]?|YO|ZE)\d(?:\d|[A-Z])? \d[A-Z]{2})"

    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = UKPostCode
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    If REMatches.Count = 0 Then
        ValidatePostCode = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        ValidatePostCode = REMatches(0)
    End If

End Function
```

Edit:  I thought it wasn't working as it only return **E17 3RU** which is in Walthamstow, but **HE17 3RU** isn't a valid postcode (http://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode) so it found the valid one.

Comment: Sorry yes, I changed all the details of the address - don't want to get in trouble! I'll edit question

Comment: Yep, definitely don't use real data. :)